# Find text in my tables, stored procedures, and views in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am able to search for specific text in my views and stored procedure, but I'm not able to search through my tables at the same time.

Here is what I have:

```
DECLARE @cmd           VARCHAR(1000),
        @search_string VARCHAR(200)

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    [Database_Name]     sysname,
    [Schema_Name]       sysname,
    [Object_Name]       sysname,
    [Object_Type]       nvarchar(60) 
)

-- Set the search string
SET @search_string = 'text'

SET @cmd = 'INSERT INTO #temp SELECT DISTINCT ''?'', s.name AS Schema_Name, o.name AS Object_Name, o.type_desc FROM [?].sys.sql_modules m INNER JOIN [?].sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id INNER JOIN [?].sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id WHERE m.definition Like ''%' + @search_string + '%'''

-- Uncomment the following if you have problems with your command and want to see the command
--PRINT @cmd

-- Run for every database on the server
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @cmd

-- Retrieve your results from the temp table
SELECT *
FROM #temp
ORDER BY [Database_Name], [Object_Name], [Object_Type]

-- If you want to omit certain databases from your results, simply add 
-- the appropriate WHERE clause, as in the following:
--SELECT *
--FROM #temp
--WHERE db NOT IN ('DB1', 'DB4', 'DB7')
--ORDER BY db, obj_type, obj_name

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Are you wanting to look for table or column names? Or are you wanting to look at the data in those tables?

Comment: Check if a column name in the table contains the text

Comment: To look for a column with a given names the easiest thing to do is query sys.columns where name = 'Whatever'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this query for column search

```
SELECT 
    t.[name]    TableName
    , c.[name]  ColumnName
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE t.[type] = 'U' 
AND c.[name] LIKE '%Text%'
```

Below script will get result for all the databases for both Tables and other obejcts.  Hope this will help.

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
DECLARE @SearchWord VARCHAR(20) = 'Text'
CREATE TABLE #Search (DatabaseName VARCHAR(255),SchemaName VARCHAR(50),ObjectName VARCHAR(255),ObjectType VARCHAR(50))

SET @command = 'USE ? INSERT INTO #Search
                    SELECT DB_NAME(), SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id),t.[name] TableName, ''Table'' FROM sys.columns c INNER JOIN sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id WHERE t.[type] = ''U'' AND c.[name] LIKE ' + '''%' + @SearchWord + '%'''
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command;

SET @command = 'USE ? INSERT INTO #Search
                SELECT DISTINCT DB_Name(),s.name AS Schema_Name, o.name AS Object_Name, o.type_desc FROM sys.sql_modules m INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id WHERE m.definition Like ''%' + @SearchWord + '%'''
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command 
SELECT * FROM #Search;
DROP TABLE #Search
```

Comment: I want to search through all my DB in the server and i want to search the stored procedures and views as well

Comment: Added script for global search. Please try

Comment: Thanks! The second part is exactly what I was searching for

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way

```
select 
 object= object_name(c.id), o.name , o.type
from sys.syscomments as c
join sys.objects as o on c.id = o.object_id
where c.text like '%Id%'
```

All compiled objects are in *sys.comments*, the name changed a few times depending on the version of SQL you have, the sample is from the current version.

Now, one doesn't need to join sys.object as the TSQL is in the text column.

You can look for any string that you have used, table names, field names or code comments. the sample shows %ID% looking for all function, trigger, views procedures that have something that contains the letters ID.

You know that when clicking on an object in SSMS you can select show Dependencies right?

[image: Right click object and select "show Dependencies"]