# Find a specific text string in a Stored Procedure, Function, View or Trigger

Tags: sql-server

I want to find a text or column name where I use in Stored Procedure, Function, View and Trigger.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find text in my tables, stored procedures, and views in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49929087/find-text-in-my-tables-stored-procedures-and-views-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 4):

You can easily query the stored object definitions in numerous ways, one way is

```
select o.[name], o.type_desc 
from sys.sql_modules m
join sys.objects o on o.object_id=m.object_id
where m.definition like '%<search text>%'
order by o.type_desc, o.[name];
```

Comment: I would add `o.type_desc` next to `o.Type` . It reads a bit easier imho

Comment: correct syntax is "order by"